# How can i get phtml file in helper magento 2?

Tags: magento2, phtml, helper

I have tried this solution but it is not working

```
$this->_layout->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Productdesigner');
       $response = $layout->setData(array("customer_data" => $result))->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::test.phtml')->toHtml();
```

get an error when i have used above solution

```
Invalid template file: 'Vendor_Module::test.phtml' in module: 'Vendor_Module' block's name: 'productdesigner_0
```

I have add phtml file in below path

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/test.phtml
```

Comment: Please clarify more to make it understandable.

Comment: what you are trying to do?

Comment: I need to get phtml file data using helper file.

Answer (score 2):

Please use this

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::test.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For Ex. if you call helper function from controller, then you can call PHTML and get data using following way :

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * @var \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $helperData;

    /**
     * [__construct description]
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http   $request    [description]
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context    [description]
     * @param \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data            $helperData [description]
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $helperData
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->helperData = $helperData;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->helperData->getPhtml();
    }
}
```

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $registry;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * [__construct description]
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry          [description]
     * @param PageFactory                 $resultPageFactory [description]
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory

    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function getPhtml()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')
            ->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::test.phtml')
            ->toHtml();
        print_r($block);
    }
}
```

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/test.phtml

```
<?= "PHTML file"; ?>
```

I hope it will helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::test.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you @Kazim But it is get error "Notice: Undefined variable: block in". I need to get phtml file data using helper file.